# Is it safe to unset the msftdata flag on a ext4 partiton that was reformatted from ntfs?

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, ntfs

As part of my shedding windows I've been changing the partitions on my legacy drives from ntfs to ext4 by doing the copy / format / copy back dance.  This has gone well, but I noticed in gparted that the msftdata flag is still set on the partitions.  Is it safe to unset this flag?  And is there any reason to,  other than to remove all taint of 'ms' from my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe, and no there is no real reason to: linux ignores this flag.

Comment: I confirm it is safe and only restore Linux partition on description, instead of msftdata for gparted.