# How can I add msftdata flag to an ext4 partition?

Tags: dual-boot, ext4, windows-10, gdisk

I have moved my partitions around to make room for dualboot, and now Windows 10 is on sda1 and sd2, with my linux install on sda3 (boot) and sda4 (home). I would like to access sda4 from my Windows install and am attempting to use Ex2Fsd in Windows. From what I understand, in order for this to work in Win10 I need to add the msftdata flag to my existing partition. I assumed I could do this in gparted, but there is no option for that. I installed gdisk, but don't know what commands to issue. I have a good backup of my partition.

Comment: That ... is a windows question tp me. gparted does have the msftdata flag (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/371487/is-it-safe-to-format-msftres-msftdata-and-hidden-partitions/371605 ) but looks like is it and GPT related and windows related.

Comment: IMHO it's an Ubuntu question, as it is not possible to do this manipulation in Windows, but rather one can do it in Gdisk or parted. It also appears that the reason the gparted doesn't have the flag has to do with the fact that it's using an old version of parted.

Comment: This is weird to me because I just used gparted to remove these flags from partitions, but I guess you can't add them.  I asked about it here http://askubuntu.com/questions/724475/is-it-safe-to-unset-the-msftdata-flag-on-a-ext4-partiton-that-was-reformatted-fr

Comment: May be because my disks are GPT.

Answer (score 1):

Solution as follows:

1-run Gdisk from CLI
2-select disk (in my case it was /dev/sda)
3-select partition (in my case 4)
4-select "t" to change a partitions "type" code
5-enter "0700"